# Scraping div with a data- attribute using Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have to scrape a web page using BeautifulSoup in python.So to extract the complete div which hass the relavent information and looks like the one below:

`<div data-v-24a74549="" class="row  row-mg-mod term-row">`

I wrote `soup.find('div',{'class':'row  row-mg-mod term-row'})`.
But it is returning nothing.I guess it is something to do with this data-v value.
Can someone tell the exact syntaxof scraping this type of data?

Comment: What's the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
content = """
<div data-v-24a74549="" class="row  row-mg-mod term-row">"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'html.parser')
for div in soup.find_all("div", {"class" : "row"}):
    print(div)
```